# How to use UndoRedoSupport or undoSupport of glazedlist in JTable?

Tags: java, swing, undo-redo, glazedlists

I have created a JTable with GlazedList eventList.
I searched the API but i couldn't figure out how to add undo/redo possibility to this table. I found in the API following classes:

`UndoRedoSupport undoRedoSupport = new UndoRedoSupport<"what here?">("argument?");
 UndoSupport undoSupport = new UndoSupport<"what to write here?">("argument?");`

**Does any body know how to use it?**

```
private void createComponents() {
    EventList<Dien> eventList = new BasicEventList<Dien>();
    actionList  = GenericsUtil.makeList();
    table  = new WebTable();
    searchField = new WebTextField(60);
    String[] headers = new String[]{"Code", "Name", "Number"};
    String[] properties = new String[]{"Code", "Name", "Number"};
    TextFilterator<Dien> dienFilterator = new TextFilterator<Dien>() {
        public void getFilterStrings(List baseList, Dien dien) {
            baseList.add(dien.getCode());
            baseList.add(dien.getName());
            baseList.add(dien.getNumber());
        }
    };
    MatcherEditor<Dien> textMatcherEditor = new TextComponentMatcherEditor<Dien>(searchField, dienFilterator);
    eventList = toolModel.getDiens();
    FilterList<Dien> filterList = new FilterList<Dien>(eventList, textMatcherEditor);
    TableFormat tableFormat = GlazedLists.tableFormat(properties, headers, new boolean[]{true,true,true});
    model = new EventTableModel<Dien>(filterList, tableFormat);
    model.addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
        public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
            if(e.getType()==TableModelEvent.UPDATE){
                if(!panel.isPendingChanges())
                    panel.setPendingChange(true);
            }
        }
    });
    selectionModel = new EventSelectionModel<Dien>(filterList);

    table.setSelectionModel(selectionModel);
    table.setModel(model);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Undo/Redo classes built in to GlazedLists does not come with a public constructor; instead you *install* support to a particular eventlist via the `UndoRedoSupport.install()` static method.

Of course, if you're using Swing then it makes sense to leverage Swing's `UndoManager` class and GlazedLists provides a simple wrapper with its `UndoSupport` class. Again this is simply initialised with its `install()` method.

I've created a simple Swing sample application as an example to illustrate how to use these classes. In my example I'm using a simple `EventList` of Strings and a JList. But it will apply the same to any GlazedList-backed component -- `UndoRedoSupport` applies to the `EventList` itself and not the Swing component.

```
import ca.odell.glazedlists.BasicEventList;
import ca.odell.glazedlists.EventList;
import ca.odell.glazedlists.swing.EventListModel;
import ca.odell.glazedlists.swing.UndoSupport;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.undo.UndoManager;


public class GlazedListsUndoSample {

    private JFrame mainFrame;
    private JButton addItemButton;
    private JButton undoButton;
    private JButton redoButton;
    private UndoManager undoManager;

    private EventList<String> eventList = new BasicEventList<String>();

    public GlazedListsUndoSample() {
        //populateAvailableBooks();
        createGui();
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);

    }

    private void updateButtons() {        
        //addBookButton.setEnabled(!books.isEmpty());
        undoButton.setEnabled(undoManager.canUndo());
        redoButton.setEnabled(undoManager.canRedo());
    }

    private void createGui() {
        undoManager = new UndoManager();
        UndoSupport.install(undoManager, eventList);

        mainFrame = new JFrame("GlazedLists Undo Example");
        mainFrame.setSize(600, 400);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        EventListModel model = new EventListModel(eventList);
        JList list = new JList(model);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        mainPanel.add(new JScrollPane(list), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel addBookPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        addBookPanel.add(new JLabel("Item"), BorderLayout.WEST);
        final JTextField titleTextField = new JTextField(50);
        addBookPanel.add(titleTextField, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        addItemButton = new JButton("Add Item");
        addItemButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                eventList.add(titleTextField.getText());

                updateButtons();
            }
        });
        addBookPanel.add(addItemButton, BorderLayout.EAST);


        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();

        undoButton = new JButton("Undo");
        undoButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (undoManager.canUndo()) {
                    undoManager.undo();
                }

                updateButtons();
            }
        });

        redoButton = new JButton("Redo");
        redoButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (undoManager.canRedo()) {
                    undoManager.redo();
                }

                updateButtons();
            }
        });

        updateButtons();

        buttonPanel.add(undoButton);
        buttonPanel.add(redoButton);

        mainPanel.add(addBookPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        mainPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        mainFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        mainFrame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              new GlazedListsUndoSample();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

It's worth noting that the [documentation](https://svn.java.net/svn/glazedlists~svn/tags/glazedlists-1_9_0/www/api/index.html) does strongly hint at its functional limitations:

> Not every change described in a ListEvent results in an undoable edit.
>   Specifically, a mutation of a list element IN PLACE does not produce
>   an undoable edit. For example, an ObservableElementList which observes
>   a change of an element, or a call to List.set(int, E) with the same
>   object at that index produce a ListEvent that does not have a
>   corresponding UndoRedoSupport.Edit object. These ListEvents are
>   ignored because they lack sufficient information to undo or redo the
>   change.
>
> In general UndoRedoSupport only makes sense for use with a
>   BasicEventList or a trivial wrapper around a BasicEventList which does
>   not affect the order or type of the elements, such as an
>   ObservableElementList. Advanced transformations, such as SortedList or
>   FilterList will not work as expected with this UndoRedoSupport class
>   since their contents are controlled by information outside of
>   themselves (Comparators and Matchers).